# Generating sine wave from noisy pulsed signal

Tags: clock

I have a pulsed signal approximately 80MHz, 40mV amplitude. I need to create a clock signal for an ADC which requires a phase locked sine wave of about 0.5Vpp.

Is there a simple COTS solution for this? Or something that can be easily built?
Can I just filter with an 80MHz bandpass + opamp amplifier? Do I need a PLL?

Example of input signal:

[image]

Comment: An ADC requires a sine wave clock? Really? What part?

Comment: so12311 are we done with this Q and A now --> [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If the waveform in your picture is precisely the waveform that you wish to convert to a clock then use a high speed comparator - maybe the MAX999 will be adequate. If the signal is dancing around DC wise then you can feed the MAX999 +input with the actual signal and low pass filter the signal and feed it to the -input. A simple RC network will do that.

It's called a data slicer: -

[image]

Image from [Manchester Data Encoding for Radio
Communications APPLICATION NOTE 3435 by Maxim](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3435.pdf) or from [ADI - Manchester Data Encoding for Radio Communications](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/manchester-data-encoding-for-radio-communications.html).

You can take it much further when the average level is moving about a fair bit. The circuit below does peak detection of most positive and most negative parts of the waveform and produces a "mid-rail" that both tracks the average (even quite fast moving average values) and also compensates for magnitude shifts of the signal: -

[image]

Image from [Data Slicing Techniques for UHF ASK Receivers](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/data-slicing-techniques-for-uhf-ask-receivers.html).

I've done the same but at 80.19MHz - don't ask why it was 80.19MHz - it is a long story.

Comment: Running the signal through filters will introduce a phase shift. This may or may not be a problem, but it will affect the relative timing of the ADC samples.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm suggesting that +input gets the raw signal whilst -input gets a much-more-dc version of that signal i.e. the comparator becomes a data slicer circuit. See my circuit addition.

Comment: Sorry, but I was referring to the requirement that the clock output must be a sine wave - which I frankly doubt, but that's what he says.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yeah that's very odd!! All will be clear in the morning!